# Empty post params in rails when the request came from go NewRequestWithContext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, go, ruby-on-rails-5, http-post

I am using rails 5 to get a post request from go script, i have a route with post to my function.

In go script, i am using this code to do post request and send the data:

```
request, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, post, url, bytes.NewBuffer(data))
resp, err := client.Do(request)
```

In rails, I using this code to get the parameters of the post request

```
params = params.permit!.except(:controller, :action).to_h
```

The pb is that params are empty `{}` when i do the request from go.

But i can see the data in request raw body by doing in rails:

```
puts request.raw_post
```

In rail:

```
  request.headers["Content-Type"]: 
  "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

Data in go :

```
data, err := json.Marshal(jsonData)
```

Comment: Are you providing the correct `ContentType` header with the request? Can you give us an examply of the request body and the headers?

Comment: I already added this in go: 
request.Header.Set("Content-Type", http.DetectContentType(data))

Comment: Does that give you the expected content type on the Rails side? You can get the headers via `request.headers`. I'm guessing there is a missmatch so rack is not deserializing the request body.

Comment: In rails, request.headers["Content-Type"]:

"text/plain; charset=utf-8"

Data in go :
data, err := json.Marshal(jsonData)

Comment: Well thats your problem right there. You need to send `application/json`. I don't really know go but can't you just do `request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")` as you actually know what you should be sending?

Comment: Yes. Can you write that as anwser so i can i select as anwser it please
@max. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to answer the question yourself. I don't really want to answer questions where I don't actually understand the code in question.

Answer (score 2):

I must provide the correct ContentType header with the request in go by do

```
request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

It is json as i am sending json. If not the case, rails will not understand the request body and will not be able to use params.